# How to use SSH for web application login?

Tags: ssh, login, apache-2.4

Is it possible to hook a web application's login to an SSH server? I'd like to have access to a web control panel hooked to an SSH user group. They could use the same password for the control panel login as they would for their normal SSH account. It doesn't need to give them SSH access- just do the username/password authentication. Ideally, it could use their SSH key to auto-login, when they visit the control panel, but I'm skeptical that that is possible.

Comment: Hopefully this is the correct SO site for this question...

Comment: what operating system?  You should be able to use something like Auth_pam to auth against the passwd DB for http_basic auth, or are you implementing your own auth?.    You will not be able to use their private key to login. Also if you go down this way make sure to implement rate limiting so $BAD_GUYS cannot just sit and try to crack accounts this way.

Comment: It is a Debian 6 server. I would prefer to have a custom login page. PAM looks promising though. I've never used it, but I guess there's a MySQL plugin that might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a large part your question translates to: I want my web application to authenticate users against the system user database (`/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`  and `/etc/group`), just like SSH does. The jargon for the Linux system authentication layer is PAM, pluggable authentication Modules.

The quickest is most likely to configure Apache to provide PAM support. A recipe is to run [pwauth](https://code.google.com/p/pwauth/wiki/InstallApache) and [mod_authnz_external](https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/) resulting in a Apache configuration looking similar to:

```
DefineExternalAuth pwauth pipe /usr/sbin/pwauth

<Directory /var/www/yourapp>
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Your app requires authentication" 
 AuthBasicProvider external
 AuthExternal pwauth
 # any valid username/password is allowed access
 Require valid-user
 ## Only bob and sarah allowed
 # Require user bob sarah
 ## Only the members of the group yourappusers are granted access
 # Require group yourappusers
</Directory>
```

In larger environments the local file based user authentication is often replaced with a central user directory, typically a LDAP directory. On the system level that is question of changing the PAM configuration after which all application that need authentication are instantly LDAP aware.

There's a Apache [LDAP module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html) as well although typically most applications would support LDAP authentication natively, rather then relying on Apache. That also allows things like a "log off" button to work, functionality which doesn't exist with Apache auth.

SSH keys are specific to the SSH protocol and although you may find rebuilding that functionality  in a web application an interesting challenge, you should know that the commonly used rough equivalent of SSH public key authentication in web applications is to deploy SSL client certificates.

Comment: I ended up installing the PAM PECL extension for PHP.

Answer (score -2):

If you actually need the encryption SSH provides, you could do the following:

Have Apache listen just on localhost on the server that also runs SSHd. Nothing else if you want to keep it secure. Then you simply create a SSH tunnel to the server, which redirects to itself to the port where Apache is listening.

This could be done like so: `ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:80 user@yourserver.com` (this is for OS X)

When the connection is established, you can just go to localhost:8080 in the browser on the remote (client) machine and access the webpage.